# There is a way to monitor what procedure is taking time when sending a form? And there is a way to speed up? (jQuery validator)

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation, submit

I have a form validated with jQuery validate. The questions may vary between 17 input fields and 50 input fields (it's a survey). My validation is always running (I didn't put a listener on my Validate instance).

Here is the code:

```
$("#dati").validate({
    validClass: "evvai",
    rules:{
        
        nomeAzienda:{
            required: true,
            pattern:  /^(?=.{2,}$)(([0-9a-zA-ZàáâäãåąčćęèéêëėįìíîïłńòóôöõőøùúûüųūűÿýżźñçčšžÀÁÂÄÃÅĄĆČĖĘÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏĮŁŃÒÓÔÖÕŐØÙÚÛÜŲŪŰŸÝŻŹÑßÇŒÆČŠŽ∂ð ,\.\'\-\?\:])?(?!))+$/          },
        indirizzo:{
            required: true,
            pattern: /^(?=.{2,}$)(([0-9a-zA-ZàáâäãåąčćęèéêëėįìíîïłńòóôöõőøùúûüųūűÿýżźñçčšžÀÁÂÄÃÅĄĆČĖĘÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏĮŁŃÒÓÔÖÕŐØÙÚÛÜŲŪŰŸÝŻŹÑßÇŒÆČŠŽ∂ð ,\.\'\-\?\:])?(?!))+$/           },
        cap:{
            required: true,
        
            pattern: /^(?=.{2,}$)(([0-9a-zA-ZàáâäãåąčćęèéêëėįìíîïłńòóôöõőøùúûüųūűÿýżźñçčšžÀÁÂÄÃÅĄĆČĖĘÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏĮŁŃÒÓÔÖÕŐØÙÚÛÜŲŪŰŸÝŻŹÑßÇŒÆČŠŽ∂ð ,\.\'\-\?\:])?(?!))+$/           },
        citta:{
            required: true,
            
            pattern: /^(?=.{2,}$)(([0-9a-zA-ZàáâäãåąčćęèéêëėįìíîïłńòóôöõőøùúûüųūűÿýżźñçčšžÀÁÂÄÃÅĄĆČĖĘÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏĮŁŃÒÓÔÖÕŐØÙÚÛÜŲŪŰŸÝŻŹÑßÇŒÆČŠŽ∂ð ,\.\'\-\?\:])?(?!))+$/           },  
        provincia:{
            required: true,
            
            pattern: /^(?=.{2,}$)(([0-9a-zA-ZàáâäãåąčćęèéêëėįìíîïłńòóôöõőøùúûüųūűÿýżźñçčšžÀÁÂÄÃÅĄĆČĖĘÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏĮŁŃÒÓÔÖÕŐØÙÚÛÜŲŪŰŸÝŻŹÑßÇŒÆČŠŽ∂ð ,\.\'\-\?\:])?(?!))+$/           },
        partitaIva:{
            required: true,
            
            pattern: /^(?=.{2,}$)(([0-9a-zA-ZàáâäãåąčćęèéêëėįìíîïłńòóôöõőøùúûüųūűÿýżźñçčšžÀÁÂÄÃÅĄĆČĖĘÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏĮŁŃÒÓÔÖÕŐØÙÚÛÜŲŪŰŸÝŻŹÑßÇŒÆČŠŽ∂ð ,\.\'\-\?\:])?(?!))+$/           },  
        email:{
            required: true,
            pattern: /^(([a-zA-Z]|[0-9])|([-]|[_]|[.]))+[@](([a-zA-Z0-9])|([-])){2,63}[.](([a-zA-Z0-9]){2,63})+$/           },
        
    },
    messages:{
        
        nomeAzienda:{
            required: "Campo obbligatorio",
            pattern:  "Caratteri ammessi: alfanumerici, accentate latine, spazio. Simboli ammessi: trattino(-), apostrofo ('), virgola(,), punto(.),punto interrogativo(?)."
        },
        indirizzo:{
            required: "Campo obbligatorio",
            pattern:  "Caratteri ammessi: alfanumerici, accentate latine, spazio. Simboli ammessi: trattino(-), apostrofo ('), virgola(,), punto(.),punto interrogativo(?)."
        },
        cap:{
            required: "Campo obbligatorio",
            pattern:  "Caratteri ammessi: alfanumerici, accentate latine, spazio. Simboli ammessi: trattino(-), apostrofo ('), virgola(,), punto(.),punto interrogativo(?)."
        },
        citta:{
            required: "Campo obbligatorio",
            pattern:  "Caratteri ammessi: alfanumerici, accentate latine, spazio. Simboli ammessi: trattino(-), apostrofo ('), virgola(,), punto(.),punto interrogativo(?)."
        },  
        provincia:{
            required: "Campo obbligatorio",
            pattern:  "Caratteri ammessi: alfanumerici, accentate latine, spazio. Simboli ammessi: trattino(-), apostrofo ('), virgola(,), punto(.),punto interrogativo(?)."
        },
        partitaIva:{
            required: "Campo obbligatorio",
            pattern:  "Caratteri ammessi: alfanumerici, accentate latine, spazio. Simboli ammessi: trattino(-), apostrofo ('), virgola(,), punto(.),punto interrogativo(?)."
        },  
        email:{
            required: "Campo obbligatorio",
            pattern:  "Inserisci un email valido."
        }
    },
    invalidHandler: function(event, validator){
        
        console.log("form ko");
    },

    errorPlacement:function(error, element){
    
        var campo = element.parent();
        
        campo.css("position", "relative");
        $(".error-container").appendTo(campo);
        error.appendTo($(".error-container"));
        $(".error-container").fadeIn(300);
        
        setTimeout(function(){
            $(".error-container").fadeOut(1000);
            
            setTimeout(function(){
                
                campo.css("position", "static")
                $(".error-container").empty();
                $(".error-container").appendTo("body");}, 1500)
            
        }, 4000);
    },

    submitHandler: function(form){
        
    $(form).submit();
  }
});
```

The problem occurs when I send the form. It takes sometimes 10 or 15 seconds to submit, and, meanwhile the website is completely stuck.
I'd like to know where I should look in Chrome DevTools to monitor this procedure, and how could I speed up the process. Maybe, if I couldn't do much to speed up submitting, I'd like to know how could I put a pre-loader (I don't know which event to put event listener on etc).

Thank you.

Comment: Devtools > performance tab. If something is that slow I'd expect it to be based on network issues and/or server side performance

Comment: @RoryMcRossan, I'm sure is a client side problem because I'm on local web server and my forms (even on this page) always had a normal submitting time.